# How to convert files in s3 from intelligent tier to standard tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have LZO files in a S3 bucket, except for the latest LZO files rest are all in Intelligent tier storage class, if i run my spark program on top of the Intelligent tier LZO files the output is not complete (not same like when run on Standard Class data both) both in terms of data and resultant file size.

i found the following way for glacier to standard

```
$ aws s3api restore-object --bucket awsexamplebucket --key dir1/example.obj --restore-request '{"Days":25,"GlacierJobParameters":{"Tier":"Standard"}}'
```

I did a s3 copy from the current bucket location to a new locationn and that converts data from Intelligent to standard

is there any other way to convert Intelligent tier to standard storage class, if not what else is the work around for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Did you able to figure it out why in IA you were having data issues. ?

Answer (score 3):

To change storage class of an existing object, you have to copy it using [copy-object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/copy-object.html). From [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html#sc-howtoset):

> You can also change the storage class of an object that is already stored in Amazon S3 to any other storage class by **making a copy of the object** using the PUT Object - Copy API.

Comment: (a) AWS SDK lets you copy onto itself, for in-place update. Hadoop fs rename() command does a copy to a new directory tree, so should do the right thing too.